# How do I support both intel cpu and amd gpu using opencl?

Tags: opencl

So, Intel SDK works with intel cpu, gpu, and xeon phi.
AMD SDK works with AMD gpu and cpu.

I would like to develop an application that targets intel cpu and AMD gpu.
Can anyone suggest a development strategy to achieve this?

Thanks.

Edit: I would like to run both cpu and gpu kernels concurrently on the same system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get list of available platforms, in case of Intel CPU/AMD GPU you shall have 2 platforms, each with it's own ID.

Usually, that's it, you create devices an so on, using necessary platform ID in each case.

If you are using Windows, it's not so difficult to see in debugger, that different platforms corresponds to different OpenCL libraries (just go deeper into cl_platform_id structure) - both of dll's are loaded.

Comment: Thanks, Roman. So, using the intel sdk, I tried to build a program for AMD and it crashed. Someone on the AMD news group said that intel does not support AMD GPU, so this is why it crashes. But, with ICD, this should not matter, right? I should be able to use intel sdk to build for AMD. Yes?

Comment: I have been developing for nVIDIA 1 year, and when I tried my app in AMD it worked without any change. If that does not happen to you, its because you are doing something that is platform specific. In theory it should work straight away. BTW What does "it crashed" means? It does not compiles? It compiles and then crashes at some point? Then you are good to go for a coffee and a debug time :)

Comment: Thanks, DarkZeros. clBuildProgram crashes with access violation. In AMD ocl dll. I have posted this on AMD forum - looks like a bug in AMD library.

Comment: @Jacko you have an answer on the AMD forum. Aparently some of your API calls in the kernel are not ok, and Intel accepts them but AMD not.

Answer (score -2):

Put your OpenCL code (not necessarily the kernel) in a library and create and link the DLL files for the AMD and Intel (and NVIDIA) devices.  Create a new program and dynamically load the library based on which platforms the user has installed.

Kind of a pain in the butt but it works in Labview so it should work in other languages.

If you are using Windows, you can use [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) and put the library in a folder that is in your PATH (Windows Environment Variable) or in the same folder as the .EXE.

Comment: Thanks, Austin. See edit above. I would like to run both cpu and gpu kernels at the same time. So, intel cpu kernel and amd gpu kernel together. Is this possible? I would think this is quite a common configuration.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with OpenCL, though you could put the bulk of your calculations on the GPU and run optimized code on the CPU.  If you do your Kernel right, converting to straight C is a breeze.  Throw in some OpenMP and if might get you where you need to be.

Comment: The OpenCL Installable Client Driver (ICD) already does this dynamic loading behind the hood, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I thought his edit was in regards to running GPU and CPU code in parallel at the same time, not selecting at runtime which device and platform.